# Amazon s3 SDK for php can not get Bucket object list

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was getting list of object from a bucket but it getting error of endpoint.

```
define('AWS_KEY', 'xxxxxx');
define('AWS_SECRET_KEY', 'x+x/xxxxxxxx/');
define('AWS_CANONICAL_ID','xx');
define('AWS_CANONICAL_NAME', 'xxxxx');
$HOST = 's3.amazonaws.com';
require_once 'php_plugins/aws/v1/sdk.class.php';

$Connection = new AmazonS3(array(
 'key' => AWS_KEY,
 'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
 'canonical_id' => AWS_CANONICAL_ID,
 'canonical_name' => AWS_CANONICAL_NAME,
));

$ListResponse = $Connection->list_buckets();
$Buckets = $ListResponse->body->Buckets->Bucket;
foreach ($Buckets as $Bucket) {
    echo $Bucket->Name . "\t" . $Bucket->CreationDate . "\n";
    $response = $Connection->list_objects($Bucket->Name);
}
```

I am getting response.

```
[body] => CFSimpleXML Object
    (
        [Code] => PermanentRedirect
        [Message] => The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
        [Bucket] => pics.online.com
        [Endpoint] => pics.online.com.s3.amazonaws.com
        [RequestId] => 5F102571A54DA3BA
        [HostId] => tBBxwxfUbdlV+m1R/Z9BnjLViyjROdzXrhPfc28WHaZYo/1zAwof2C0G5CVpZvkP8oZERTL0CD8=
    )

[status] => 301
```

I think error is in URL 
code call "host name/bucket name"
here I have change my bucketname
    https://s3.amazonaws.com/pics.online.com/
it should call 
    https://pics.online.com.s3.amazonaws.com/

can you anyone tell me how to change this path for amazon s3 PHP?

Comment: Where do you put your S3 bucket? If it is not US standard, don't forget to set your region.

Comment: @EdwardSamuel I have set region but it show AWS Error Code: PermanentRedirect, Status Code: 301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
require 'aws-autoloader.php';

$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$bucket = "";
$s3 = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory([
    'signature' => 'v4',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'http' => [
        'verify' => '/home/ubuntu/cacert.pem'
    ],
    'Statement' => [
        'Action ' => "*",
    ],
//    'debug' => [
//        'logfn' => function ($msg) {
//            echo $msg . "\n";
//        },
//        'stream_size' => 0,
//        'scrub_auth' => true,
//        'http' => true,
//    ]
        ]);

try {
  $objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
      'Bucket' => $bucket //bucket name
  ));

 echo "Keys retrieved!\n";
 foreach ($objects as $object) {
     echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
 }
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
 }
?>
```

download the sdk from [AWS PHP SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/quick-start.html)

> **UPDATE**

First check you system for AWS Compatibility by using the following files.

https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/tree/master/_compatibility_test

you can use **cacert.pem** for fetching whole data from AWS S3.

you can download **cacert.pem** from **[here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)**. and modify your `php.ini` by adding below code.

```
curl.cainfo = D:\xampp\php\cacert.pem
```

Here is the code I use on my local machine for fetching data without https. I have PHP V5.6 .

```
require 'aws-autoloader.php';
$s3 = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'key' => '************',
                'secret' => '*************',
            ),
              'signature' => 'v4',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
        ));
   print_r($result = $s3->listBuckets());
```

if you face errors in following format. you can use array format for initializing S3 object.

Comment: code I provided is only of 38 lines. can you tell me what is causing is error? which variable or condition?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/public_html/i.php on line 6

Comment: are you using AWS SDK? if yes then which version?

Comment: are you using the same code as provided by me or using it with you own code?

Comment: here is the documentation which also working same as my code.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html

Comment: I am getting error
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client(['version'     => 'latest','region'      => 'ap-southeast-1','credentials' => $credentials]);

Comment: where is your `aws-autoloader.php`

Comment: Same error at last  Endpoint error.
Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\PermanentRedirectException: AWS Error Code: PermanentRedirect, Status Code: 301

Comment: @Nileshpatel : have you checked your server for AWS Compatibility ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the bucket name using the set_hostname method...

```
$Connection->set_hostname($HOST); // Set the hostname
$Connection->allow_hostname_override(false); // Stop the hostname being changed later.
```

Your code should then read as follows...

```
define('AWS_KEY', 'xxxxxx');
define('AWS_SECRET_KEY', 'x+x/xxxxxxxx/');
define('AWS_CANONICAL_ID','xx');
define('AWS_CANONICAL_NAME', 'xxxxx');
$HOST = 's3.amazonaws.com';
require_once 'php_plugins/aws/v1/sdk.class.php';

$Connection = new AmazonS3(array(
 'key' => AWS_KEY,
 'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
 'canonical_id' => AWS_CANONICAL_ID,
 'canonical_name' => AWS_CANONICAL_NAME,
)); 

$Connection->set_hostname('pics.online.com.s3.amazonaws.com');
$Connection->allow_hostname_override(false);

$ListResponse = $Connection->list_buckets();
$Buckets = $ListResponse->body->Buckets->Bucket;
foreach ($Buckets as $Bucket) {
    echo $Bucket->Name . "\t" . $Bucket->CreationDate . "\n";
    $response = $Connection->list_objects($Bucket->Name);
}
```

Comment: it show 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'cURL_Exception' with message 'cURL resource: Resource id #9; cURL error: (cURL error code 51). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes.' php_plugins/aws/v1/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php:847

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which region is your buckets in. I thought you have multiple buckets in multiple regions. You can not call object related operation using `S3Client` for different region. It's only working for a specific region.

```
<?php

define('AWS_KEY', 'AKIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('AWS_SECRET_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('REGION', 'ap-southeast-1');

require_once 'aws-sdk-php-3.4.0/aws-autoloader.php';

$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => AWS_KEY,
        'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    ),
    'region' => REGION,
    'version' => 'latest',
));

$listBuckets = $client->listBuckets();
foreach ($listBuckets['Buckets'] as $bucket) {
    // Get bucket location
    $location = $client->getBucketLocation(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket['Name']
    ));

    // Print bucket information
    echo $bucket['Name'] . "\t" . $bucket['CreationDate'] . "\t" . $location['LocationConstraint'] . "\n";

    // Check if the bucket location is in client region
    if ($location['LocationConstraint'] == $client->getRegion()) {
        $listObjects = $client->listObjects(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket['Name']
        ));

        foreach ($listObjects['Contents'] as $object) {
            echo $object['Key'] . "\t" . $object['Size'] . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "--> The bucket is not in " . $client->getRegion() . ". Skipped.\n";
    }
}
```

If you are working on multiple regions, you can create separated `S3Client` for each region.

Comment: My bucket is in ap-southeast-1 regions.

Comment: Hi, have you tried to run my code? Check whether you have some buckets in outside `ap-southeast-1` region from the output.

Comment: yes, your code is working. How can I check file exist in a bucket?